# Segmentation fault with wiringPi

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, segmentation-fault, wiringpi

I'm fairly new to coding, and I've been trying to write something to write a placeholder to a text document whenever a button attached to a GPIO pin on my RasPi is pressed:

```
//Write date function//
void record() {

    ofstream myFile;
    myFile.open("report.txt");
    myFile << "Input at SPAM \n";
    myFile.close();

}

//myRead function//
void myRead(int i){

    if((digitalRead(4) == HIGH) && (i<5)) {
        record();
        digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(14, LOW);  
        ++i;
        delay(500);
        myRead(i);
    }   
    else{
        if((digitalRead(4) != HIGH) && (i<5)){      
            myRead(i);
        }
    }

}   

int main() {
    wiringPiSetup();
    pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(14, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(4, INPUT);
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(14, LOW);

    myRead(1);
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    delay(5000);
    digitalWrite(14, LOW);

    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles without any complaints, but if I run it in terminal without a `sudo` command, I get a "segmentation fault" error.
When I run it with a `sudo` command, the program starts and then ends almost immediately.

For reference:

- Pin 12 is providing power to a potential divider on the breadboard.
- Pin 4 should take the input from this divider.
- Pin 14 causes an LED to light whenever there is an input on pin 4.

Whenever I run the program and VERY QUICKLY press the button on the potential divider, the LED will light if I hold the button.

How can I get this to run properly without it stopping as soon as it starts?

Comment: The `myRead` probably recurses to much in the time it takes you to press the button. To find out build with debug information (add the `-g` flag when compiling and linking) and then run in a debugger to find out when and where the crash happens, and see if the function call-stack is full of calls to `myRead`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.  My code was indented in the source file, but I wasn't sure about the format here.  Edited the indentation for now, but I've been teaching myself c++ for less than a month, so I get that my code's pretty messy and hard to read.

Comment: That seems to be the issue.  I get the output:  "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00010b6c in myRead (i=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xbe7ffffc>) at inputReport.cpp:18
18      void myRead(int i){".  I'm not really sure what to do about it.  Any suggestions on how I could have the system check for an input every few seconds?

Comment: Do it in a *loop* instead of recursive calls?

Comment: I'll try using a "while" loop.  I had tried using a "while" loop in conjunction with my "if else" commands, but not by itself.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly using the "while" loop!  I was really stumped by that one, but I'll learn from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are several possible problems with `myRead`.

A minor rewrite could be:

```
void myRead(int i)
{
    if((digitalRead(4) == HIGH) && (i<5)) {
        record();
        digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(14, LOW);  
        ++i;
        delay(500);
        myRead(i);
    } else if((digitalRead(4) != HIGH) && (i<5)) {
        myRead(i);
    }
}
```

Notice that you have two calls to `digitalRead` -- this may lead to problems since the first one my return something different from `HIGH` and the second may return `HIGH`, meaning neither conditions are true.

You make a call to `myRead` with the same `i` in the alternative branch as the original call. If `digitalRead` returns something different from `HIGH` suffeciently many times, your stack will be full very fast and you'll get a segfault.

I'll propose a different version, that *should* be identical (baring any misunderstanding on my part):

```
void myRead(int i)
{
    // as long as i is less than 5
    while (i < 5) {
        // busy wait for digitalRead(4) to be HIGH
        while (digitalRead(4) != HIGH);
        // do the main thing
        record();
        digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(14, LOW);  
        ++i;
        delay(500);
    }
}
```

Also please note that this is just plain C, not C++ (well, technically it's valid C++, but it's making no use of C++)

Comment: That seems like it would work, but I just changed it up and used while loops, on the advice of Some programmer dude, which seems to work just fine.  Thanks for the answer!  As for the whole C/C++ thing...  I don't know a single thing about C.  I wanted to start learning a programming language, and a few people recommended C++.  I picked up the basics from the Sololearn course, but I've never had someone directly teach me.  Any suggestions on how I could get better at C++, aside from the obvious "Keep taking more challenging projects"?

Comment: Get a good book on C++ instead of some random internet course. Usually they're written by people who have learned C in the 1980's or where taught by someone who learned C in the 1980's. They have all sort of bad stuff that you don't want to learn to begin with. I recommend getting Bjarne Stroustroup's latest book that's relevant to your compiler. Hopefully that's C++11 or later (C++17 preferably). There are other good books too, but I don't know any of them so I can't comment on them.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.  I'm a year away from going to uni, and I've never done computing in school.  The course I want to do involves a fair bit of programming, but claims to teach it for complete beginners.  Despite this, I want to have a bit of an idea of what I'm doing before I go on.